# Graphviz: make edges not affecting the hierarchy of nodes

Tags: qt, graphviz

I add edges (green) to graph, that makes hierarchy of nodes. How to add minor edges (red) that not affecting on the hierarchy?

[image]

Edit: It's Qt graphViz library.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want an edge to not have an impact on ranking, you can simply set the [`constraint`](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dconstraint) attribute to `false`:

> If false, the edge is not used in ranking the nodes.

Example:

```
node1 -> node2 [constraint=false];
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is only for `dot` not the other engines. Any one know what to do for `circo`?

Answer (score 5):

You need `{rank = same; <node names> }`, e.g.

```
digraph G {
    a -> b
    a -> c
    c -> d
    c -> e
    a -> f
    c -> f
}
```

... gives:

[image]

... while

```
digraph G {
    a -> b
    a -> c
    c -> d
    c -> e
    a -> f
    c -> f
    { rank=same; c f }
}
```

... gives:

[image]

Comment: so, when i draw edges from node A, i should set same rank for nodes B, C, F?

Comment: It was only necessary in this case to set the same rank for nodes `c` and `f`, but you could be absolutely sure by setting the same rank for all three nodes on that level.

Comment: oh, i'm wtiting in Qt graphviz and there only function `setAttribute(string property, string value);`. don't know how to make  `{ rank=same; c f }` =(

Comment: I tried to setAttribute("rank", "same"); to each node on green edge, but it does'n change anything

Comment: where you draw this graphs?)

Comment: The code is written in Graphviz' language and the graphs are drawn with Graphviz' `dot` program.