# pygraphviz: adding {rank = same; node1 node2}

Tags: graphviz, rank, pygraphviz

I don't see an example for adding same rank in `pygraphviz`. Right now I'm taking the `G.string()` string and appending `{rank = same; node1 node2}` to it at the end. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In my code, `add_nodes_from()` added nodes without edges, at the same horizontal level:

```
A.add_nodes_from(["coyote", "wolf"])
```

`add_edge()` added nodes with edges in a vertical column:

```
A.add_edge(1,2)
```

Seting parameter `constraint=False` put nodes at the same horizontal level:

```
A.add_edge(previous_item, item, rank='same', constraint=False)
```

I wrote a function:

```
def add_nodes_connected_by_edges(graph, items, rank_same):
    """
    Adds nodes to graph, one node per string in items
    :param graph: a pygraphviz graph
    :param items: a list of strings
    :param rank_same: boolean. True ranks nodes so they appear at same horizontal level
    """
    previous_item = None

    for item in items:
        graph.add_node(item)
        if previous_item is not None:
            # Use constraint=False to keep rank same
            # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756929/graphviz-make-edges-not-affecting-the-hierarchy-of-nodes
            graph.add_edge(previous_item, item, rank='same', constraint=(not rank_same))

        previous_item = item
```

[graphvizzy](https://github.com/beepscore/graphvizzy) repository shows a more complete example[image: pygraphviz nodes]